# perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C")

Tags: locale, perl

I get the following errors from perl:

```
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

After doing `echo $PATH` this is the output: 
   /home/michaelcw02/bin:/home/michaelcw02/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

And I cannot do `locale` because I dont have it installed.

This is the complete output after running `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgcrypt11 libgnutls26 libslp1 libtasn1-3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgcrypt11 libgnutls26 libtasn1-3
Suggested packages:
  rng-tools gnutls-bin
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups elementary-minimal hplip language-pack-bg language-pack-bg-base language-pack-cs
  language-pack-cs-base language-pack-da language-pack-da-base language-pack-en language-pack-en-base 
  language-pack-gnome-bg language-pack-gnome-bg-base language-pack-gnome-cs language-pack-gnome-cs-base
  language-pack-gnome-da language-pack-gnome-da-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
  language-pack-gnome-hu language-pack-gnome-hu-base language-pack-gnome-id language-pack-gnome-id-base
  language-pack-gnome-ja language-pack-gnome-ja-base language-pack-gnome-ko language-pack-gnome-ko-base
  language-pack-gnome-nb language-pack-gnome-nb-base language-pack-gnome-nl language-pack-gnome-nl-base
  language-pack-gnome-pl language-pack-gnome-pl-base language-pack-gnome-sv language-pack-gnome-sv-base
  language-pack-gnome-th language-pack-gnome-th-base language-pack-gnome-tr language-pack-gnome-tr-base
  language-pack-gnome-uk language-pack-gnome-uk-base language-pack-gnome-vi language-pack-gnome-vi-base
  language-pack-hu language-pack-hu-base language-pack-id language-pack-id-base language-pack-ja
  language-pack-ja-base language-pack-ko language-pack-ko-base language-pack-nb language-pack-nb-base
  language-pack-nl language-pack-nl-base language-pack-pl language-pack-pl-base language-pack-sv
  language-pack-sv-base language-pack-th language-pack-th-base language-pack-tr language-pack-tr-base
  language-pack-uk language-pack-uk-base language-pack-vi language-pack-vi-base language-pack-zh-hant
  language-pack-zh-hant-base printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-splix
  ubuntu-minimal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgcrypt11 libgnutls26 libtasn1-3
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 73 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/786 kB of archives.
After this operation, 258 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "es_CR.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Some nice error messages you do have... in what context do they occur? And what is your question?

Comment: I am kind of newb here so.... Ill try to do my best to describe it 

It happens when I try to do "sudo apt-get -f install", but it started when I was trying to install Skype, and something came up saying that in order to continue I have to type 'Yes, do as I say' 

So, my question is... is there a way to fix this??

Comment: OK, you installed _Skype_ and chose the russian approach concerning [EULAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement): "Just click OK". Now, this proprietary software(_Skype_) seems to have messed with your system configuration. Without further (detailed) information (which should be added/edited to your question) it is unlikely that anybody can offer you an easy solution.

Comment: Can you please run the command `locale` in a terminal window and let us know what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: Possibly the `PATH` environment variable has been messed up. That can't reasonably have happened because you tried to install Skype. But to check that, can you also let us know the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: `PATH` looks good, but not being able to run `locale` is really, really bad. As ubfan1 said you need to install the `libc-bin` package. If you can't do that easily (I fear you can't), your system is in such a bad state that you'd better reinstall the OS.

Comment: In fact, I did. I've just reinstalled the whole thing. I guess I have to be more careful when I try to install something.

Comment: I think so too. Especially when you are suggested to remove packages to be able to install. As a general rule, install from the Ubuntu archive at first hand.

Answer (score 1):

Both /usr/bin/locale and /sbin/ldconfig are in package libc-bin.
Install that package to fix your errors.